# Ruby: How can I display input results (in a list) if they are available, and hide the list item if there is no value present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of list items I'd like to show. Some will have values and some won't. If they all have values great, but if only 3 values have values, how do I hide the list items without a value?

```
<li><%= @post.color %></li>
<li><%= @post.make %></li>
<li><%= @post.model %></li>
<li><%= @post.cupholder %></li>
```

I thought I could do something like

```
<% if @post.attr.each do %> 
  <li><%= @post.color %></li>
  <li><%= @post.make %></li>
...
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if @post.make %>
  <li><%= @post.make %></li>
<% end %>
```

but I can't get it, and now I'm not even sure what to ask / search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
<% unless @post.color.blank? %><li><%= @post.color %></li><% end %>
<% unless @post.make.blank? %><li><%= @post.make %></li><% end %>
<% unless @post.model.blank? %><li><%= @post.model %></li><% end %>
<% unless @post.cupholder.blank? %><li><%= @post.cupholder %></li><% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to user a helper to keep your view code clean, something like (`posts_helper.rb`)

```
module PostsHelper
  def li_unless_blank(val)
    val.blank? ? '' : "<li>#{val}</li>"
  end
end
```

and in your view

```
<%= li_unless_blank @post.color %>
<%= li_unless_blank @post.make %>
<%= li_unless_blank @post.model %>
...
```